# How to return key and value from map faster?

Tags: java, collections

I have block of code which find some key in cached map.And if used returns that
 key and value by `get`.

```
private Map<String, Map<Character, Integer>> cache = new HashMap<>();
if (cache.containsKey(inputData)) {
    return cache.get(inputData);
}
```

So , i use two finding operatins.Can i do it with one find? or how can i do it faster?

Comment: You just do get and then a null check.

Comment: Could u write the example code?

Comment: What else do you return if it does not contain the key?

Comment: Then goes logic,it`s for cache

Comment: @YaroslavTemchenko check the answers and try to understand what's happening there. Cache is not going anywhere. If any answer resolved your question, accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just call `get()` method and than compare returned value to `null`.

```
final Map<Character, Integer> value = cache.get(inputData);
if (value != null) {
    return value;
}
```

Comment: I would suggest not to use final for `value` and compute `value` if not found in cache. As I suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46913657/how-to-return-key-and-value-from-map-faster/46913722#46913722)

Answer (score 1):

Try `getOrDefault`.

```
cache.getOrDefault(inputData, defaultValue);
```

It will return the value corresponding to the key if there is one, otherwise the default value will be returned.

Also note that `get`'s time complexity is `O(1)` so in terms of complexity, your code is pretty fine. Also remember that premature optimisation is the root of all evil.